# Error while trying upload Artifact to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

What i try to upload is this jar:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4

with GAV Parameters taken from here (see screen below):

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.4</version>
```

Currently i don't have this version in my 3rd party:

[image]

what i get is this error:

[image]

The error says:

```
Artifact upload failed.
Could not store item to repository "3rd party" [id=thirdparty], path ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.pom', requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@101f160e, parent=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@68e0f966, parent=null}}, pathStack=[], processedRepositories=[thirdparty], appliedMappings={}}(GAVCE=org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:3.4:c=null:e=pom, for "3rd party" [id=thirdparty])
```

Nexus configuration:

`Repository Policy`: `Release`

`Deployment Policy` : `Allow Redeploy`

Before i added many artifacts successfully with my account.

`Log` file:
http://wklej.org/id/3074345/

How can i successfully upload this artifact?

Comment: Maybe you should rebuild the metadata for the repository and try again.

Comment: @JFMeier option `Rebuild metadata` on 3rd party did not fix it.

Comment: Check the nexus.log file, there should be more information there about this failure.

Comment: @rseddon  I added the log file: http://wklej.org/id/3074345/

Comment: @rseddon  Thanks. It was my friend fault - that he added files as `root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diagnosing log file: wklej.org/id/3074345
I found out that some files in `/opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/thirdparty/` had been added by `root`
so i changed them to user `nexus` with command:
`chown -R nexus:nexus maven`